# Pivot table conditions are bad practice?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relational-database

I have a pivot table for a many to many group of records.
Consider the following structure

A has many B
B has many A
A has many C
C has many A

if **A** has multiple **B** in this table and I want to pull only specific **B** from the list I would need to add an additional column to the pivot table.

For example

Pivot:

A1 - B1 - filter_pen
A1 - B2 - filter_pineapple
A1 - B3 - filter_apple
A2 - B1 - filter_pen

I want all **A**s with **B**s that represent a `filter_pen`. I can therefore rely on that filter column. This to me SEEMS correct.

When you then consider that **C** entries have absolutely no relation to **B** entries except the fact they also can have **A** entries, the filter column is very generic and could be used very differently depending on the type of entry connecting to **A**.

For this reason is there an industry standard approach to this problem, and would this be considered bad practice? Are there inherent factual (not opinionated) problems with this method?

Comment: It's not easy to follow your description without a more specific example with data. But it sounds like your tables are not in Fourth Normal Form. I.e. you're trying to use your "filter" column for multiple relationships. I've answered several questions about that in the past, see some of them here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20860+fourth+normal+form

Comment: This is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Consider a [mre]. Suggest: Find & follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens are online free in pdf & html. There are sometimes free online university/college courses. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) Ask a specific researched non-duplicate question where 1st stuck/unsure.

Answer (score 0):

A "many-to-many mapping" table is appropriate whenever "many:many" is the "relationship" between two "entities".  The other relationships (like this) do not need an extra table:  1:many and 1:1 involve simply an id in one table that 'points' to the other table.

"pivot" is usually used to refer to rearranging the output to have multiple columns instead of multiple rows.  (This does not seem to be your use of "pivot".)

What *may* be the issue (I can't tell from your Question) is the used of multiple Entity tables (apples, pineapples, etc) when you should have a single table.  Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to describe the tables.